# Can a member operator overload override a library operator overload?

Tags: c++

I like to use libtins library which overloads the `/` and `/=` operators. However for a specific user class I have I want to use this same syntax but also set a private member. Since I cannot use `-ffriend-inject`, I figured I would override via a unary member function apart of that class. I recall having been successful with this before but I was wondering whether that is considered undefined behavior? what is the official stance of the c++ committee?

small example (untested I am on mobile atm).

```
#include <tins/tins.h>

class Example : public Tins::PDU {
private:
  bool has_pdu = false;

public:
  bool empty() const { return !has_pdu; }

  Example &Example::operator/=(const Tins::PDU &pdu) {
    *this /= pdu;
    this->has_pdu = true;
  }
};
// ...sometime later
Example msg;
msg /= Tins::RawPDU("test");

if (!msg.empty())
  std::cout << "msg is not empty!" << std::endl;
```

the templated binary definition for `/=` can be found
https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/blob/eb997f54384c5105a1ec49d7683fa1131d8fa23c/include/tins/pdu.h#L551-L581

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with some examples?

Comment: The linked template function demands a cast from `T*` to `PDU*` on the first line. That overload is going to [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) out on pretty much any type that isn't `PDU`, so you have nothing you need to fight against.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sorry I forgot to add the `public Tins::PDU` to the class def.

Comment: BTW the example I have above isn't showing the 3-4 pure virtual overrides that need to be present. I could add those if needed but really I was hoping to get an answer relating to the rules that function overload resolution takes in the scenario where there is a templated binary operator overload AND a member function unary overload. For the same operator.

Comment: which in this case is `/=`.

Comment: `/=` is a binary operator. Writing it as a member function doesn’t change that; it still takes two arguments. Like all member functions, it has an implicit argument that’s a pointer to the class that it’s a member of.

Comment: @PeteBecker right. But in this question I am asking which overload _should_ be called on the line `msg /= Tins::RawPDU("test");`. That is, what result should I expect given by the lang standard. The def I given above? (I.e., `has_pdu` will get updated) or the def given by the tins lib?

Comment: @skyfire -- you need to change your title and your question to not talk about unary operators.

Comment: @PeteBecker I see your point now, sorry about that. Fixed.